# Google spreadsheet query execute for entire column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I tried **VLOOKUP** function for two separate Google spreadsheets but it doesn't support, So I figure it out my required function with a **`QUERY`** using a **`ImportRange`** function.

Here it is:

```
=QUERY( ImportRange( "sheet key" , "Course Data!A2:I4" ) , "select Col2 where Col1 = '" & E2 & "' limit 1" )
```

This is execute well for selected cell, it return value from the second spreadsheet according to the value of the current sheet **`E2`** cell.

What I want to achieve is run this query for entire column (E3, E4, E5...)

I am new to Google Spreadsheets and saw something on internet with **`ARRAYFORMULA`**. But I couldn't apply it here.

Comment: See the answer for a similar question regarding QUERY in Web Applications - Stack Exchange http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78115/queryimportrange-throws-formula-parse-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wrong !
`VLOOKUP` supports for two different spreadsheets.

This is work fine:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(Vlookup(E2:E,ImportRange( "sheets key (url in new sheets)" , "Course Data!A2:I4" ) ,2,False)))
```

Cheers!